# Input Stream from MongoDB in JSP

Tags: json, jsp

I'm trying to write a method that takes a JSON object that is stored in a mongoDB and serves a ical/ics file to the user.
This is my code so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ical", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getIcalFile(
        String json,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        // get your file as InputStream
        InputStream is = //Input stream from JSON. HOW?
        // copy it to response's OutputStream
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //log.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '" + fileName + "'");
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writinethod that takes a JSON object and serves a ical/ics file to the user. This is my code so far:g file to output stream");
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to take an JSON object and use it as an input stream. If there is a better way to do what I am trying to achieve, I would love a suggestion.

Comment: So what gives with the MongoDB tag? How do you actually have the data stored?

Comment: I should have been clearer. Data is stored in mongodb.

Comment: To paraphrase the movie title "Dude, where's your code?" Nothing in your question references retrieving data from MongoDB at all. So perhaps edit your question to show what you have tried.